# C++ Synchronization object - InitializeConditionVariable Failure

Tags: c++, synchronization, operating-system

I have a very simple question regarding OS conditional variables:
Why the initialization doesn't succeed?

Here is my code:

```
CONDITION_VARIABLE a;  
void foo()  
{  
    InitializeConditionVariable (&a);  
}
```

The variable a is not initialized properly - contains NULL pointer..
I'm using windows Vista 32

Comment: I don't know what exactly is wrong, but you can call [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and see what error has occurred.

Comment: How do you know that a null pointer is not valid? What happens if you try to use it?

Comment: @Alan Stokes You are right! the null pointer was valid! I thought it was wrong because the SleepConditionVariableCS never returned but it appeared to be a problem with the CriticalSection and not the condition variable. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My mistake. Strange but the null pointer returned from the InitializeConditionVariable is correct and can be used. My problem was with the SleepConditionVariableCS which never returned but it appeared to be a problem with the CriticalSection and not the conditional variable...